# Firefox won't open some web sites

Tags: firefox, debug

I am running Firefox 74.0 on Linux Mint. Since v73, I have been facing the problem that some web sites will open very slowly (e.g. github.com) while others will not open at all (e.g. www.elster.de), ending in a "connection timed out" message. It also occurs if I call my router via firefox. The majority of sites however works just fine. What I tried so far without success:

- complete removal of Firefox and re-install
- Disabling Ghostery and other privacy protection add-ons.
- Deleting the cookie for the respective site.
- The built-in debugger is also not of much help because the site does not open at all.

What can I further do to narrow down the cause of this problem?

Comment: And other browsers experience no issue?

Comment: yes of course. it's not a problem of the respective web sites

Comment: I just tried with www.elster.de and it works for me (Firefox Dev Edition, latest build; Windows 10 Pro x64), so unless you've got other content blockers than Ghostery (I use NoScript and uBlock myself, along with Decentraleyes) that could explain that, maybe you should check your hosts file.

Comment: As I said, I switched off content blockers. what do you mean by hosts file?

Comment: www.elster.de opens fine for me in Ubuntu 18 / Firefox 74 64-bit.  It was a little slow in opening. Have you checked the Privacy settings in Firefox Preferences?  They may be too strict.

Comment: www.elster.de was very slow for first open. Message was establishing secure connection. Check your enabled cyphers.

Comment: thanks @harrymc. "enabled cyphers"...what do you mean by that?

Comment: See [Manage cipher suites in Firefox](https://www.ghacks.net/2016/04/18/manage-cipher-suites-firefox/). I wonder if you are missing some, or that Firefox needs to run through a lot of them until it finds one that works for this website.

Comment: thanks. that gives me a list of 15 ciphers, all of them enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by

1. removing Firefox completely via Synaptic
2. deleting `~/.cache/mozilla/firefox`
3. deleting `~/.mozilla`
4. re-install Firefox